# Java: String vs StringWriter?

Tags: java, string, stream, byte

If I have an array of bytes(which could be from fairly large file), which is better for constructing a String?

```
new String(byteArr, UTF_8);
```

vs

```
try (final ByteArrayInputStream decompressed = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
     final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {

  IOUtils.copy(decompressed, stringWriter, UTF_8);
  return stringWriter.toString();

} catch(...) {//...}
```

Is there any benefit to using `StringWriter` here?

Comment: There's no advantage to using StringWriter

Comment: Where do you even get that second part? It looks like it comes from a decompression logic that gets extracted and then adapted without understanding the reasoning.

Comment: Are you certain the bytes represent text?

Comment: `String s = Files.readString(Paths.get("... .txt"));` would be better - if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to convert from a byte array you already have, that represents UTF-8 text, to a single `String`, then `new String(bytes, UTF_8)` is unambiguously the best, most efficient solution.

If any of those aren't true, e.g. you are reading the file incrementally, the situation may change, but you will have to specify the situation.

Answer (score -1):

For small to moderately sized byte arrays, use new String(byteArr, UTF_8) for simplicity and efficiency. For very large files or stream-based processing, consider the ByteArrayInputStream approach, but it's more complex.